# Href link to subfolder

Tags: asp.net, href, master-pages

I have created a masterpage with a submenu folder called "County_Polices".  Within the subfolder I have the file "Cty_911_calltaking.aspx".

On the master page I have tried the 3 below scripts and none will open up the aspx file within the subfolder.

```
 <li><a href="#">911 Calltaking Polices</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><li>
                                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Cty_911_calltaking.aspx">County Police</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Cty_911_calltaking.aspx") %>">County Police 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="~/County_Polices/Cty_911_calltaking.aspx">County Police 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
```

What am I doing wrong.

This is the source code of the Cty_911_calltaking.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Cty_911_calltaking.aspx.cs" Inherits="OnCallWeb.County_Polices.Cty_911_calltaking" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            font-size: xx-large;
            color: #009999;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: x-large;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
    test<table class="auto-style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2"><em><strong><span class="auto-style3">Header</span></strong></em></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style4">Enter text here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
&nbsp;
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard I found the error.  Was a simple typo.  Using the below code works:

```
<li><a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/County_Polices/Cty_911_calltaking.aspx")%>">County Police 1</a></li>
```